# When should CSS font-family value use quotes?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

When should the value for CSS 'font-family' have quotes around it?

I've seen both `font-family: arial` and `font-family: "arial"`.

As a specific example, I declare a font this way:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'entypo';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('/css/fonts/entypo.woff') format('woff');
}
```

What would be the correct CSS to have an element use this font-family?

Comment: So, basically your question is, *"in which CSS standard is this specified?"*.

Comment: I had read an article about that explaining that even non-quoted values WITH spaces like Times new Roman would work - but I unfortunately don't have the url on hand. Know that the internals on that are quite complicated and have to do with the actual name of the font-family...

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos: Uh, that seems [pretty easy to verify, even without an article.](http://jsfiddle.net/HMVHr/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need quotes when the font itself has a space such as `"Times New Roman"`.

`Arial` does not need quotes, but some people use quotes such as `"Arial"` to be more consistent. It is simply personal preference.

Seen in Justin's below comment: `font-family: times new roman;` works without quotes ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMVHr/)).

You can call your new `@font-face` using `font-family: 'entypo';` as you would normally expect. ([link](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/))

Comment: Right, adding quotes even on a single word has the benefit of consistency across CSS.

Comment: TIL Adding quotes around a name makes the name more precise. `:P`

Comment: Oh? You [need quotes around Times New Roman](http://jsfiddle.net/HMVHr/)?

Comment: @JustinSatyr I stand corrected, thanks.

Comment: This is a common misconception: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-font-family

Comment: FYI, where times new roman doesn't need quotes.  The barcode font **code 128** does.  It's probably because of the second word starting with a number.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvao239t/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just going to answer from this:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop

To avoid mistakes in escaping, it is recommended to quote font family names that contain white space, digits, or punctuation characters other than hyphens:

body { font-family: "New Century Schoolbook", serif }

Font family names that happen to be the same as a keyword value ('inherit', 'serif', 'sans-serif', 'monospace', 'fantasy', and 'cursive') must be quoted to prevent confusion with the keywords with the same names.

Answer (score 1):

By the CSS 2.1 [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#value-def-family-name), a font name *needs* to be in quotes if it contains characters other than [identifier characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (which is a broader concept than just “Ascii letters and digits”) and spaces. So `font-family: foo bar` is correct, and so is e.g. `font-family: entypo` of course.

Coding style is a different issue. It is always correct to quote a specific font family name (as opposite to generic names like `sans-serif`), so `font-family: "entypo"` is correct, too.

Very theoretically, a font name also needs to be quoted if a specific font family name coincides with a generic name (I don’t think anyone ever created such a font) or if its name contains leading or trailing spaces or consecutive spaces (but no one in his sense would name his font that way).

Comment: `font-family: foo bar` is **not** correct if `foo bar` is the name of the font. It should be in quotes.

As a side note, I've seen both "Serif" and "Monospace" used as font family names.

Comment: @bfrohs, please consult the specification cited. You can also use http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ And you *can* use quoted `"Serif"` as a font name, it is syntactically valid; but it makes no sense, since there is no such font family.

Comment: The spec cited specifically says "to quote font family names that contain white space". Ergo, your example (`font-family: foo bar`) should be `font-family: "foo bar"`. I know you *can* use `"Serif"` quoted--I was pointing out I *have* seen fonts named both `Serif` and `Monospace` before.

Comment: @bfrohs, check the spec again: there is a requirement, and there is a recommendation; there is a difference between “shall” and “should”. And I don’t thin you have seen *fonts* named Serif and Monospace; just (incorrect) `font-family` values with such names in quotes.

Comment: I'm actually looking at my system fonts ;)