# Do fonts with spaces need to be enclosed in quotes?

Tags: css

Looking at values for the `font-family` attribute I sometimes see `"Helvetica Neue"`enclosed in quotes and other times I see for example `More Pro` without quotes.  Do `font-family` values that contain spaces need to be quoted or is it ok to just use `Helvetica Neue`?

There's an answer to this here [when-should-css-font-family-value-use-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228792/when-should-css-font-family-value-use-quotes), so also wondering whether this is current?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-family-prop), no it isn't required, but it is recommended.

> Font family names other than generic families must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted as a sequence of one or more identifiers. This means most punctuation characters and digits at the start of each token must be escaped in unquoted font family names.
>
> To avoid mistakes in escaping, it is recommended to quote font family names that contain white space, digits, or punctuation characters other than hyphens:

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should.

In my stylesheet, I always do enclose font with spaces as it keeps things in order.

The main reason is that, browsers will see it as a single font value, which make sense.